# Annotation processing third party libraries

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, annotation-processing, android-binding-adapter

I'm writing an annotation processor for an Android project and have run into a situation. I would like to process annotated classes from a library module, i.e. app module depends on library module and needs to process annotated classes from the library module.

However, the annotation processor isn't able to "see" the annotations from the dependency, presumably because the code is already compiled. See [here](https://github.com/atteo/classindex/issues/26) for an issue on another library. A demonstration of the problem with my project is on the branch [here](https://github.com/saadfarooq/Khoji/tree/so-demonstration). The annotations from `sample` module are processed but the ones from the `lib` module are not.

This is all well and good and I'd resigned myself to living without this feature, but it turns out the Android data-binding library can process annotations from modules and even third party libraries. [This](https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter) library, for example, provides `@BindingAdapter` methods that are processed fine by the app.

I played around with setting retention types on the annotations I use to no avail. The only significant difference I can see is that the data-binding processors target methods while my methods target classes (types), but I don't think that should make a difference from the processor. So I'm thinking it might have something to do with the data-binding processor being part of the Android plugin but I'm not sure how that helps here.

Anyone know how this is done?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Is there an example you can provide that doesn't do what you want it to? Compiled or not shouldn't matter as far as I'm aware, as long as the retention policy is Runtime.

Comment: My understanding is that it shouldn't matter for Runtime processor annotation but it does for compile time processor annotation, which is the more commonly used pattern on Android for performance reasons. I don't have an example project set up right now, but including the ClassIndex project I reference in any project you have should demonstrate the problem as mentioned in the referenced issue.

Comment: "*the annotation processor isn't able to "see" the annotations from the dependency, presumably because the code is already compiled*" - The reply in the link you gave us says "*The custom processor 'sees' only classes which are compiled.*" Seems like you didn't read the reply. It could contain information that may solve your issue.

Comment: No, you confuse the two usages. He means that the annotation processor runs during the compile process, therefore it "sees" the classes that are passed to the java compiler. The classes from any third party dependency are precompiled so they are not "seen" by the compiler for the project undergoing compilation, they are packaged as is.

Comment: That really has nothing to do with compile/non-compiled limitations though. That's just how that particular library works. I think you've polluted the question with non-relevant information. Perhaps I'm simplifying things too much, but it seems like the question is simply how to scan an external library for annotations.

Comment: If you meant "an external library for annotations", then yes, that's what the basic question is. The reason I added all of that information is to avoid the standard "what have you tried?", "you must be doing something wrong, it just works", "more details please", etc. comments you get on SO. Didn't work though... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Edited with a link to project demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Data Binding can't process annotations on dependencies, either. Instead, it processes the libraries at the compile time of the library and saves the information to an intermediate file as part of its archive (e.g. jar file). It then loads that intermediate file information from the dependency instead of reading the annotations.

If you save the intermediate information as a resource of the jar file dependency, you can pull it from the jar file pretty easily. If I recall correctly, it should be in your class path and you can use the ClassLoader's getResource() method. My memory may be a little stale on this as it doesn't use the jar file to store the intermediate file information any more.

Comment: I thought about that too, but the data-binding generated files are written by the plugin at compile time, so that means the resource files (from the dependencies) would need to be read by the plugin so it can include references to them in the generated files. So that implies that assets from dependencies are available to the plugins at build time? I wouldn't have thought that to be the case.

Comment: Yes, assets are available to the application at build time. All resources must be merged so you can access them from your application.